# using HTML5 file API to render to-be-uploaded image in a div

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display the image a user chooses upload in a div after he selects the file which is to be uploaded.

I am using HTML5 file API to perform this, but this code doesn't seem to work as I am unable to see any the photo in the div.

```js
function readerImage(file) {
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(event) {
    var the_url = event.target.result;
    $('#holder').html("<img src='" + the_url + "'>");
  };

  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

$("#img").change(function() {
  console.log(this.files);

  // grab the first image in the FileList object and pass it to the function
  renderImage(this.files[0])
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm" method="POST" action="{{ path('system_cpic') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <div id="holder"></div>
  <input type="file" name="upload" id="img" />
  <input type="submit" value="change picture" />
</form>
```

The `#holder` is supposed to show the pic but it isn't. There is some problem with the JS, can anyone find it?

Comment: so should I replace it with : var the_url = instanceOfFileReader.result; as I want to generate a URL here

Comment: The problem is you have named your function `readerImage()`, but you are trying to call it as `renderImage()` in your change event

Comment: ohh.. crap! that was silly, thanks!